# how to escape JSON in Mule

Tags: json, escaping, mule, mule-studio

{"response":{"message":"#[json:/offers[0]/offerHTML"}}

This is the actual response at runtime:

{"response":{"message:""

Is there way to escape the JSON response in mule?

Comment: Can you explain little bit more on what you want? and post piece of XML code to understand batter.

Comment: See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/35123959/2392172). It may help.

Answer (score 0):

Depends on how you are building that payload. But if you are just using strings you can use String.valueOf so that it does not evaluate the MEL expression:

```
#[String.valueOf('#[json:/offers[0]/offerHTML]')]
```